# Changing the MacBook Pro insert/eject CD sound

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro, disc

Every time I put a CD into my MacBook Pro or eject a disc from it, it makes a noise like as if it is spoilt. Is there a way to change this noise?

Comment: By sounding like it's spoilt do you mean whingeing and demanding sweets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The noise you describe is completely normal. Every slot-in drive makes some noise as it pulls in or ejects the disk.

You should also hear some noise from the drive when you start your MacBook or wake it from sleep. This is absolutely normal too.

And no, you can't change that noise.

---

#### Apple resources

From [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1723) (emphasis mine):

> You may notice your optical disc drive makes various sounds even if a CD or DVD isn't in the drive. The noises you might hear from the optical drive are **probably normal**. There is a small motor in the drive that spins discs.

#### Sample sounds

Here are some sample sounds that show you what the drive can sound like (AIFF files).

- Waking the computer from sleep ([sample](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_wake.aiff))
- [Burning](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh854.html) a CD or DVD ([sample](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_DVD.aiff))
- Inserting a disc ([sample-1](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_mbinsert.aiff), [sample-2](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_mbpinsert.aiff))
- Ejecting a disc ([sample-1](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_mbeject.aiff), [sample-2](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_mbpeject.aiff))
- Importing ("ripping") an audio CD in iTunes ([sample](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_ripping.aiff))
- Playing a DVD ([sample](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_DVD.aiff))
- Spinning up an idle disc  ([sample-1](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_mbspinup.aiff), [sample-2](http://a248.e.akamai.net/7/248/51/3054781201801120/www.info.apple.com/images/kbase/305478/305478_mbpspinup.aiff))

Comment: @Daniel I have to confess they're not from me but I think they come in quite useful here ;)

Comment: I would have been surprised if they were, given the URLs ;)

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll have to deal with the "spoilt" sound.

Comment: dang it spoils all the sleekness of macbook pro